# CursorLeakDetecter: App didnt close database... in some stock Android code. How do I obtain control over that

Tags: android

In the app we are using a popular piece of code floating around on the internet to fetch images from the gallery and on a particular tablet, I get this error:

```
12-15 11:21:49.551: E/CursorLeakDetecter(2759): PossibleCursorLeak:content://media/external/images/media/,QueryCounter:6

12-15 11:21:49.551: E/CursorLeakDetecter(2759): android.database.sqlite.DatabaseObjectNotClosedException: Application did not close the cursor or database object that was opened here
```

The problem occurs in this line of code:

```
try {
    thumb = MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.getThumbnail(mContext.getContentResolver(), position, 12345, MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.MICRO_KIND, null);
            } catch (OutOfMemoryError er) {
    er.printStackTrace();
    return null;
            }
```

But how do I close the cursor/db for an operation that happens in some Android classes and I have no control over?

Here is a bigger part of the stacktrace:

```
12-15 11:21:49.551: E/CursorLeakDetecter(2759): PossibleCursorLeak:content://media/external/images/media/,QueryCounter:6
12-15 11:21:49.551: E/CursorLeakDetecter(2759): android.database.sqlite.DatabaseObjectNotClosedException: Application did not close the cursor or database object that was opened here
12-15 11:21:49.551: E/CursorLeakDetecter(2759):     at android.content.ContentResolver.query(ContentResolver.java:397)
12-15 11:21:49.551: E/CursorLeakDetecter(2759):     at android.content.ContentResolver.query(ContentResolver.java:314)
12-15 11:21:49.551: E/CursorLeakDetecter(2759):     at android.provider.MediaStore.getImageThumbnailId(MediaStore.java:2524)
12-15 11:21:49.551: E/CursorLeakDetecter(2759):     at android.provider.MediaStore.access$000(MediaStore.java:49)
12-15 11:21:49.551: E/CursorLeakDetecter(2759):     at android.provider.MediaStore$InternalThumbnails.getThumbnail(MediaStore.java:623)
12-15 11:21:49.551: E/CursorLeakDetecter(2759):     at android.provider.MediaStore$Images$Thumbnails.getThumbnail(MediaStore.java:1054)
```

Comment: it occurs when you are not closing your cursor..

Comment: I know that. But the cursor operation happens in some Android code in the classes and methods shown in the line of code I pasted, which I have no control over.

Comment: As you don't have control on that code then you can't overcome from this error. you can remove `er.printStackTrace();` and this error won't show in logcat

Comment: Well this is true. However wont it affect performance in some way? I sometimes have this error printed infinitely and the images in the gallery never load.

Comment: its showing because cursor is not closed inside of 'getThumbnail' method. it won't create any issue in performance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This error only occur because of not closing your cursor object. you need to call `cursorobject.close()` after using cursor.

and in your case as you don't have control on that code you can't overcome with this issue and to avoid this error in log you need to comment of delete `er.printStackTrace();` from that exception block.